# Excessive Oracle Database Sessions Created by Spring's JdbcClient

Tags: oracle, spring-boot, session, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I'm encountering an issue with Spring's JdbcClient where it seems to be creating an excessive number of sessions in my Oracle database. This behavior is leading to unexpected resource consumption and potential performance problems. I'm seeking assistance in understanding and resolving this issue.

**Problem Description:**

1. **Framework/Tools Used:** I'm using Spring Boot with the JdbcClient for database interactions.
2. **Database:** Oracle Database
3. **Observation:** The application appears to be creating a large number of database sessions reach 4k session, which is impacting performance, for each execution of JdbcClient create database session.

Here's a snippet of my application

```
@Autowired
 private JdbcClient jdbcClient;

 jdbcClient.sql("query")
            .param("id", id)
             .query(String.class)
             .stream().findFirst().orElseGet(() -> "")
```

while I'm using DriverManagerDataSource to connect to oracle database

Environment Information:

Spring Boot Version: 3.2.1
Oracle Database Version: 19c

when I'm using DriverManagerDataSource JdbcClient for each time called by client it will create session
when i try to change data source from DriverManagerDataSource to HikariCP and setting connection pool
that open sessions in database when application start but when i call end point that use JdbcClient first request get succeeded but any other request getting error and doesn't open too many sessions

**error**

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30006ms.
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:696)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:181)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:146)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:100)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:160)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:118)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81)
    ... 109 more
```

what i see on database

sessions info

[image: sessions info]

i think the database are waiting from JdbcClient to end connection but there is problem with it

**more details..**
main class

```
    @EnableConfigurationProperties(RsaKeyProperties.class)
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @EnableEncryptableProperties
    @EnableAsync
    @EnableScheduling
    @EnableCaching
    @PropertySource(name = "EncryptedProperties", value = "classpath:database.properties")
    public class Application
```

service class

```
@Service
public class InfoService {
 @Autowired
 private JdbcClient jdbcClient;
public SponsorInformation getInformation(String token, PhoneType phoneType) {
String id = tokenService.decodeToken(token.substring(7)).getSubject();
return jdbcClient.sql("query")
            .param("id", id)
             .query(String.class)
             .stream().findFirst().orElseGet(() -> "");
}
```

app config class ( with hikari also try with DriverManagerDataSource )

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:database.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Value("${url}")
    private String URL;

    @Value("${dbuser}")
    private String USER;

    @Value("${driver}")
    private String DRIVER;

    @Value("${dbpassword}")
    private String PASSWORD;

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
        config.setJdbcUrl(URL);
        config.setUsername(USER);
        config.setPassword(PASSWORD);
        config.setDriverClassName(DRIVER);

        return new HikariDataSource(config);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=60000
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=-1
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=-1

spring.datasource.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.mvc.charset=UTF-8
spring.datasource.oracleucp.min-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.oracleucp.max-pool-size=405
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size =105
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle =16
jasypt.encryptor.pool-size=20
```

database.properties

```
driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
url= jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port/sid?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8 
dbuser= [database_user]
dbpassword=[encrypted_database_password]
```

Comment: There is far too little information here, but I suspect you are executing this without a proper `@Transactional` which wouldn't release the connection.

Comment: @M.Deinum  I try to add '@Transactional' from 
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
with '@EnableTransactionManagement' in main class
but what i know usage of '@Transactional' with update and delete

Comment: Don't add `@EnableTransactionManagement`. You are using Spring Boot that enables it by default (which makes me wonder what did you add more that disables auto-configuration of Spring and Spring Boot features!). You also need proper transactions for reading, there is always a transaction (explicit or implicit) so better manage it yourself. If the `@Transactional` didn't solve it then there is too little information in your question to answer this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30000ms for very tiny load server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47758091/hikaripool-1-connection-is-not-available-request-timed-out-after-30000ms-for)

Comment: @seenukarthi no dear I'm using DriverManagerDataSource  but i try Hikari when this problem happen

Comment: dear @M.Deinum I add many information also I'm using jasypt for encryption and decryption database password, also removed **@EnableTransactionManagement** and add **@Transactional** to service class ... thanks

Comment: This is what I was afraid of. Judging from the properties in use you are working around all the auto configuration from Spring Boot. Why? Use the framework don't work around it. Ditch your `AppConfig` move your `Database.properties` to `application.properties` and name them properly `spring.datasource.url` etc. Spring Boot will automatically setup things. That being said I now noticed you are using the `stream()` method. Which needs to be explicitly closed. You need to use a try with resource ideally for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [`stream()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/JdbcClient.MappedQuerySpec.html#stream()) method from the `JdbcClient`. Now if you read the documentation that method comes with one caveat:

> the result Stream, containing mapped objects, needing to be closed once fully processed (e.g. through a try-with-resources clause)

If you don't close it it will keep the underlying `ResultSet` and with that the `Statement` and `Connection` open. Modify your code to something like this.

```java
public SponsorInformation getInformation(String token, PhoneType phoneType) {
  String id = tokenService.decodeToken(token.substring(7)).getSubject();
  try (Stream<String> stream =  jdbcClient.sql("query")
            .param("id", id)
             .query(String.class)
             .stream()) {
    return.findFirst().orElseGet(() -> "");
  }
}
```

This will close the `Stream` after use and free the blocked resources.